# How to add ShellTile immediately in wide state?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, live-tile

I need that newly created ShellTile becomes wide from the beginning.
How to add ShellTile immediately in wide state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that's just not possible. When you create new tile in your app it's in medium square size by default. User need to change the tile size manually.
Note when creating new tile, don't forget to use this method with 'true' as the last parameter to signal, that the tile should support Wide size as well:

ShellTile.Create Method (Uri, ShellTileData, Boolean)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207919(v=vs.105).aspx